# Simultaneous upper-triangularization for two nilpotent commuting matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, nilpotent-matrices

Given two nilpotent matrix B1 and B2 over complex numbers which commute i.e. [B1,B2]=0, we know that they can be conjugated to upper-triangular ones (even strictly-triangular since they're nilpotent).

But, can we conjugate them to upper-triangular ones so that one of them e.g. B1 gets into its Jordan normal form?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Yes - sorry not to mention that clearly; I will edit it now. Thanks!

Comment: Not only eigenspaces, but generalized eigenspaces, are stabilized by commuting operators.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, we can conjugate $B_1$ and $B_2$ simultaneously by a matrix $S$, whose  columns are a basis of generalized eigenvectors of $B_1$, such that $S^{-1}B_1S$ is in Jordan normal form, and both $S^{-1}B_1S$, $S^{-1}B_2S$ are upper-triangular. This is possible, because commuting operators leave invariant generalized eigenspaces. On the other hand, not both of $B_1$ and $B_2$ can be simultaneously "Jordanized" in general.

For non-commuting strictly upper-triangular matrices $B_1$ and $B_2$, we may still apply 
$S^{-1}B_1S$ with those invertible $S$ which keep $B_2$ upper-triangular.
Then we may not arrive at a Jordan form for $B_1$, but to an "almost-Jordan-form", see section $2$ of the article [Modules for certain Lie algebras of maximal class](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_03_ben.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, I think I have got a counterexample for this - sorry if I am wrong:

Let $B_1=\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 & b \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0  
\end{pmatrix} $

and $B_2=\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0  
\end{pmatrix}.$

Then using matrix 

$$S=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1/b & 0  
\end{pmatrix} $$
that consists of generalised eigenvectors, we see that

$S^{-1}B_1S$ is in its Jordan normal form 

and

$$S^{-1}B_2 S=\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1/b & 0  
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: But $B_2$ **is** already in Jordan form, so it is not a counterexample.  These two matrices cannot be *Jordanized* simultaneously. This is what I meant in the answer.

Comment: True. However, instead of this $B_2$ one could use the general one (for which the question was) 

$$B_2=\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & d & e \\ 
0 & 0 & f \\ 
0 & 0 & 0  
\end{pmatrix}. $$

Then the conjugated matrix will be 

$$S^{-1}B_2 S=\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & e/b & d \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & f/b & 0  
\end{pmatrix},$$ which is not upper-diagonal in general.

Comment: Again, we only want one matrix in Jordan form. So interchange the roles of $B_1$ and $B_2$. For example, $S=\begin{pmatrix} df & e & 0 \cr 0 & f & 0 \cr 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ will put $B_2$ into Jordan form and keep both strictly upper-triangular.

Comment: True, but this works only when $S$ is non-degenerate, meaning that $d$ and $f$ are non-zero which is equivalent to saying that $B_2$ has maximal rank. 

In fact, I think that this works only then (only when the matrix you want to Jordanize has maximal rank).

Comment: No, I don't think so. Then you can use a different invertible $S$. Just come up with a counterexample, only using $1$ or $0$ as entries, such that we cannot Jordanize one of them, and keep both strictly triangular. Then I am convinced:)

Comment: Right, here is one :) Use $B1=\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0  
\end{pmatrix} $ and $B_2=\begin{pmatrix} 
0& 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0  
\end{pmatrix}.$ Assume there is a matrix $S$ such that $S^-1B_1S=\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0  
\end{pmatrix} $ and $S^-1B_2S=\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & d & e \\ 
0 & 0 & f \\ 
0 & 0 & 0  
\end{pmatrix}.$ Since B1 and B2 commute, so do the conjugated ones, giving 
$f=0.$ Then, think about the image of B1 and B2 before and after conjugation. Their intersection changes.

Comment: No, $B_2$ is already in Jordan form, and both are strictly upper-triangular.

Comment: Alright, I see where the confusion occurred. I would like the particular Jordan form, such as the one of B1 after conjugation. Sorry about not being clear about that.

Comment: The generalized eigenspace of a nilpotent matrice is the whole space, so could you please provide further elaboration on "commuting operators leave invariant generalized eigenspaces" and how it implies the second operator is then upper triangular and the first one is in Jordan normal form.

Answer (score 2):

The more general fact is that, if $N \subset \mathrm{Mat}_{n \times n}(k)$ is a subrng (ring without identity) whose every element is nilpotent, then we can choose a basis to make every element of $N$ simultaneously strictly upper triangular. This is a useful lemma which, as far as I know, doesn't have a standard name.

Note that, if $N_1$ and $N_2$ are commuting nilpotent matrices then any polynomial without constant term in $N_1$ and $N_2$ is clearly nilpotent, so this applies to the rng generated by such an $N_1$ and $N_2$.

**Proof:** Let $R$ be the $k$-algebra (with identity) generated by $N$, so $R = k \mathrm{Id} \oplus N$ and $N$ is the radical of $R$. Let $V$ be the vector space $k^n$, which we think of as an $R$-module. By the [non-commutative Nakayama Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakayama%27s_lemma#Noncommutative_case), also known as the Jacobson–Azumaya theorem, $NV \subsetneq V$. So $V \supsetneq NV \supsetneq N^2 V \supsetneq \cdots$ until we reach a power for which $N^r V=0$. Then choosing a basis of $V$ to respect the filtration by $N^r V$, we find that $N$ acts strictly upper-triangularly.

Comment: David, your result stands between the Engel's theorem and this one (due to Radjavi): Let $\mathcal{L}$ be any subset of $M_n$ that is closed under commutation $[.,.]$. Then $\mathcal{L}$ is triangularizable IFF each commutator $[.,.]$ of elements of $\mathcal{L}$ is nilpotent. cf. corollary 1.7.8 in http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387984674